# Etimologia delle parole "arzigogolo" e "arzigogolato"

Tags: etymology

In alcune novelle di Luigi Pirandello ho letto le parole "arzigogolo" e "arzigogolato", che mi sono sembrate molto curiose. Ad esempio, nella ***Tragedia d'un personaggio*** c'è questa frase:

> Avere il privilegio inestimabile di esser nato personaggio, oggi come
>   oggi, voglio dire oggi che la vita materiale è cosí irta di vili
>   difficoltà che ostacolano, deformano, immiseriscono ogni esistenza;
>   avere il privilegio di esser nato personaggio vivo, ordinato dunque,
>   anche nella mia piccolezza, all'immortalità, e sissignore, esser
>   caduto in quelle mani, esser condannato a perire iniquamente, a
>   soffocare in quel mondo d'artifizio, dove non posso né respirare né
>   dare un passo, perché è tutto finto, falso, combinato, *arzigogolato*!

Anche nel racconto ***Il buon core*** appare questo stesso aggettivo: "arzigogolato".

Nella novella ***La maschera dimenticata*** si può leggere:

> E chi sa da che strambe ragioni era stato perciò indotto a presentarsi
>   ora lí non invitato; e che cosa, nei misteriosi *arzigogoli*, nelle
>   segrete previsioni del suo spirito conturbato, doveva rappresentare
>   per lui questa sua partecipazione alla lotta politica in favore del
>   figlio di don Francesco Laleva; che beneficii sbardellati se ne
>   riprometteva, che tremendi pericoli e responsabilità si immaginava di
>   dovere affrontare...

Persino nella novella ***La veste lunga*** un personaggio, un prete, viene chiamato "don Arzigogolo".

Ho trovato nel dizionario che "arzigogolato" e "arzigogolo" sono parole che si usano per indicare qualcosa di artificioso, complicato, fatto in modo bizzarro, contorto. Mi domando, però, quale sia l'origine di queste curiosi vocaboli.

Answer (score 5):

Il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/arzigogolo/) e lo Zingarelli se la cavano con “etimo incerto”.

Si sbilancia di più il vecchio dizionario etimologico Battisti-Alessio: «sembra voce di struttura greca, forse da un latinizzato * *archaeologāre*, dal gr. *archaiologéō*, discuto di antichità o di cose fuori tempo; adopero uno stile archaicizzante», etimo ripreso dal Devoto-Oli che ho sotto mano (non il più recente).

Comment: Il GDLI (si veda risposta) sembra confermare questa etimologia come ipotesi, ma lo dà come etimo incerto.

Comment: Ottimo, grazie, @Charo.

Answer (score 3):

Dal [Vocabolario etimologico della lingua italiana di Ottorino Pianigiani](https://archive.org/details/vocabolarioetim00piangoog) (1907):

> ***arzigògolo*** (dial. *arcigògolo*). Secondo alcuni comp. di ARCI, che usato come prefisso dà forza superlativa (a cui altri sostituisce il lat. ARS *arte*) e GÒGOLO per GOLGOLO alterazione dì vòlvolo dal lat. VÒLVO *volgo in giro*. Meglio il Caix da GIRIGÒGOLO, allungamento di girigòro (v. *Girigogolo*) mediante trasposizione di lettere nel primo elemento, cioè *argi, arzi* per GIRI. — Raggiro; Giro di parole ingegnoso e bizzarro; Cavillo; Invenzione grandemente artificiosa e involuta; Ordigno fatto con minuta ricercatezza.
>   Deriv. Arzigogolare; Arzigogolóne.

Dal [Novo dizionario scolastico della lingua italiana dell'uso e fuori uso di Policarpo  Petrocchi](https://archive.org/details/novodizionarios00petrgoog) (1899)

> ***arzigogolo*** [da *girigogolo*] Trovata cavillosa. Parole rigirate. || **arzigogolare** Fantasticare.

Comment: Dunque, se ho capito bene, proviene da "arci-", come rafforzativo usato nella formazione di superlativi, e "volgo" dal verbo "volgere" col significato di girare e rigirare.

Comment: @DaG D'accordo. Grazie anche per il link!

Comment: @Charo Esatto. E tutte e due parti della parola, secondo Pianigiani, provengono dal latino.

Comment: Come si è spiegato [qui](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1202), non si può dare molta credibilità alle etimologie riportate nel dizionario di Ottorino Pianigiani.

Answer (score 1):

Secondo il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000727.jpg), "arzigogolo" è un deverbale da "arzigogolare". Per "arzigogolare" questo vocabolario dà un'etimolgia simile a quella del Battisti-Alessio riportata nella risposta di @DaG, avvertendo però che l'etimo è incerto:

> =  Etimo  incerto,  forse  da  un  lat. *archeologare*,  dal  gr. *άρχαιολογεῖν*, ' parlare  di  cose  antiche,  strane ' (comp. da *άρχαῖος* ' antico ' e *λέγειν* ' parlare ').